# Make a bootable usb drive a regular storage drive again in Windows?

Tags: windows-7, linux, hard-drive, boot, usb

I made a bootable linux drive using Win32 Disk Imager. The image I wrote on the usb drive was about 4-5 GB. When I stuck the drive in to re-use it as storage, the only part of the drive that is left is 3GB of unformatted space (total should be about 8).

I have 2 questions:

1) can I format the 3 GB and use that as windows storage? Will that mess up my linux boot drive?

2) if I wanted to wipe the drive, how would I get it back to be just storage again? Can I do this using only my Windows OS?

Comment: 1) you can, will linux boot or not depends on bootloader config, if it configured to use UUID to mount root partition, it will work. Not sure  will windows partitioning overwrite bootsector. 2) [MS repartitioning howto](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/repartition-hard-disk#1TC=windows-7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anytime you want to work with partitions in Windows, use Disk Management.  Disk Management can be found by going to `Start > Control Panel > System and Security > Administrative Tools > Computer Management > Disk Management`.

Yes, you can format the 3 GB of unused space and use it with Windows.  Yes, you can use Disk Management to remove any partitions you don't need anymore (even if they're formatted with something Windows doesn't recognize).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Minitool Partition Wizard to repartition your drive to a single NTFS/FAT32 drive which Windows can read.

The same tool can be used to format the remaining 3GB of space.

Unfortunately the built-in Disk Management snap-in (diskmgmt.msc) cannot partition drives which has partitions using filesystems not recognized by Windows.